# How can I make my two htaccess files the same in a test and live system?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For my website, I have a test directory and a live directory. Inside both I have an .htaccess file that differs slightly and I'd like to make them the same if possible. The difference between the two is that the test system does not use https while the live system does and that they have 2 different urls.

- http://www.TEST_example.org
- http://www.LIVE_example.com

**.htaccess TEST**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.TEST_example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^TEST_example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.TEST_example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

#further down...
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**.htaccess LIVE**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.LIVE_example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^TEST_example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.LIVE_example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#further down...

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

EDIT
I tried the solution from @Hello Fishy but I got

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
```

**server.config (TEST site)**

```
target_server http://www.TEST_example.org
https_switch off
```

**.htaccess modified (TEST site)**

```
RewriteMap servers txt:server.config

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^TEST_example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]

#further down...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ${servers:https_switch}
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteMap` is your answer. I'd place a `servers.txt` (or whatever you'd like to call it) in the same folder as your .htaccess (it can be in another folder though). It should include this on your TEST-system:

```
target_server http://www.TEST_example.org
https_switch off
```

and ofc this, accordingly, on your LIVE-system

```
target_server http://www.LIVE_example.com
https_switch on
```

Your rewrites have to include the servers.txt like this:

```
RewriteMap servers txt:conf/servers.txt
```

With `/conf` as potential .htaccess-folder and `servers` as the alias you'll reference in the rewrites-conf.
Then the rewrites would be the same on both systems:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap servers txt:conf/servers.txt

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ ${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^TEST_example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]

#further down...
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ${servers:https_switch}
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What about the line #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off/on which is different on each server??

Comment: You really got me there! I was searching a whole lot for a difference, thought I found it, wrote a new version, just to recognize that both have the same https-settings all the way through^^

Comment: Just added `${servers:https_switch}` since I assumed you wanted https to be turned `off` in TEST and `on` in LIVE?! Otherwise just edit the servers.txt accordingly ;)

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that assumption. I will test out your solution tomorrow and accept if it works, I'm about to leave for the day.

Comment: I made those changes and when I loaded the page I got 

`Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500`

Comment: Found at least one small mistake: `RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]` You are missing one blank and a '$' before the variable starts, like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ ${servers:target_server}/$1 [R=301,L]`